# certbot creates a certificate with "wwww" instead of a bare domain one - unlike before

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I've been creating certificates this way for over a year:

```
export website="my_domain1111.com"
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d $website -d www.$website --email hello@$website
```

and it's always created one for $website

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain1111.com
```

Today for some reason it created a one with "www" instead of a bare domain

```
export website="another_my_domain222.com"
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d $website -d www.$website --email hello@$website

# =>>>
/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.another_my_domain222.com
```

Why? has there been any change recently in certbot?

I've tried changing the order of the "-d" params - the same effect:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone  -d www.$website -d $website --email hello@$website

/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.another_my_domain222.com # with "www"
```

Version - 0.25